# Set an HTML5 Video to PAUSE when video player is out of view

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I'd like to do this with javascript. I'm building a presentation using Hakim El Hattab's [Reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/) as a foundation.

The way Reveal.js works is the current slide you are viewing has a class of .present, any previous slides have a class of .past, and any slides yet to come into view have a class of .future.

I would like it to automatically pause any video that is inside a slide set to .past or .future.

How should I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

*********************UPDATE***************************

so thanks to some direction i got over on the [css-tricks forums](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/16229/set-an-html5-video-to-pause-when-video-player-is-out-of-view) i was able to get it working on a single video using getElementById.

below is the javascript i'm using to add the .past and .future classes and simultaneously pause a video.

```
if( i < index ) {
    // Any element previous to index is given the 'past' class
    slide.setAttribute('class', 'past');
    document.getElementById('vid').pause();
}
else if( i > index ) {
    // Any element subsequent to index is given the 'future' class
    slide.setAttribute('class', 'future');
    document.getElementById('vid').pause();
}
```

the issue that i'm having now is how would i apply it to a tag name (ie: video) or possibly a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you posted your code, it makes it easier to fix:

```
if( i < index ) {
    // Any element previous to index is given the 'past' class
    slide.setAttribute('class', 'past');
    var vids = document.getElementsByClassName("past");
    for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
        vids[i].pause();
    }
}
else if( i > index ) {
    // Any element subsequent to index is given the 'future' class
    slide.setAttribute('class', 'future');
    var vids = document.getElementsByClassName("future");
    for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
        vids[i].pause();
    }
}
```

See if that helps. If it doesn't, are you using a modern and standards-compliant browser? `getElementsByClassName()` is a relatively new feature. It works in the latest version of Chrome for me.

Comment: thanks a lot petschekr! i'll definitely try this. just one thing, this presentation is meant to be sent out for clients to view so there's no telling what browsers they will be using. i'm hoping to support browsers as far back as firefox 3.6 and IE9, but if you could please let me know if it wont. i may have to resort to dropping in a getElementById for each video ewww

Comment: here's a pretty good chart of what browsers support it and which don't. If IE9 and FF3.6 are the minimum, you should be fine:
http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: thanks petschekr, this looks like it will work. thank you so much for the help good sir!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `setTimeout` would work here but you could try the following:

```
function PauseVids() {
    var vids = document.getElementsByClassName("past");
    var vids2 = document.getElementsByClassName("future");
    for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
        vids[i].pause();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < vids2.length; i++) {
        vids2[i].pause();
    }
}

// Within onLoad or $(document).ready()
setTimeout("PauseVids()", 1000);
```

Tell me if that works.

Comment: thanks petschekr. i tried to adapt this to what i have going on but i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Any JS errors? Also, what browser are you using? Try Chrome and see if it works then

Comment: failed in firefox and got the error: vids[i].pause is not a function

Answer (score 0):

@petschekr :guess this won't work, because classname past future is not only set to videoelements?!

i have no idea how reveals work and what kind of player you are using! but my way would be sth like:

there is only one file with the present class, right (current Slide)

a) define sth like a onChange function (for example on every button which changes pages + keypresses)

b) trigger that function before you switch pages

```
function onChange(){
       var currentSlice = document.getElementByClassName('present')  //get current html elemen
       var videoObjects = currentSlice.getElementsByTag('video')  //get videoelements here html5 video
       for each videoObj      
            videoObj.pause()
```

edit: pseudocode to get you an idea!

Comment: thanks for the help but i couldnt get that to work with my code.