# Pause HTML5 video when out of view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I've built a multimedia slider with images and html5 video using [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)-- [a fiddle can be viewed here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/nn3sw00f/)-- and I'm trying to find a way to automatically pause any videos that might be playing that are not active in the slider, i.e. those that are out of view. Thus, if a viewer clicks a video to play, then progresses through the slider, that video will in turn pause, so no two videos can be playing at the same time.

Slick slider appends a class of `.slick-active` to all slides currently in view, so I'm thinking I need to isolate (via jQuery perhaps) all slides containing video that *do not* have the `.slick-active` class applied, and ensure that video playback is stopped?

I found a helpful SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383725/set-an-html5-video-to-pause-when-video-player-is-out-of-view), that describes the use of `getElementsByClassName` to select video content in a slider that is not active, however I cannot employ this same method as slick slider only adds classes to those frames currently *in view*.

How might I use jQuery to select the appropriate slides and stop any active playback? Thanks in advance for any assistance here.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518546/how-can-i-stop-video-from-playing-if-not-point-view/29528275#29528275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine if the video is playing or not. If so, then hook into the slick slider `beforeChange` event to pause the video.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').addClass("loaded");
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 200,
    slidesToShow: 7,
    dots: true,
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    variableWidth: true
  });
  $("video").click(function(e) {
    // get click position 
    var clickY = (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
    var height = parseFloat($(this).height());
    var self = this;

    // avoids interference with controls
    if (clickY > 0.82 * height) return;

    // toggles play / pause
    self.paused ? self.play() : self.pause();
    $('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      if (!self.paused) {
        self.pause();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @colecmc; can you elaborate a bit? i.e. how to check playback status and link to the slick slider event?

Comment: The event documentation is at the same link you provided.